# Data coming through socket (nodejs) and push into Highchart

Tags: node.js, highcharts

[**Background**]
Well, I'm using NodeJS to fetch the value from API and I'm getting values. And socket.io is pushing the values into the browser.

[**Requirement**]
Now, how can I push that values into the HighChart to draw the chart.

Comment: Yes I'm expecting json to push into HighChart, do u've done similar ?

Comment: So when you produce JSON, then you can get it by AJAX and run chart.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show what you've tried and where you've gotten stuck, rather than asking for others to write the code for you.

Comment: Well, in my case it is only on my localhost. And, I've a bit complex app which I can not put on the public domain coz I've to install: Node, Redis (for php), Workers etc etc, which I dont want to do now (until my prof-of-concept gives me some output on graph). Here, I'm getting json object (one at a time) through Workers (lets say channels) here I want to push that into the HighChart (that is the problem) - Hope you understand.

Comment: But what exactly is problem? Chart is blank? You have errors in console? We understand that you can show what are you working on, but at least precize your problem. Does simple creating chart without values work? Are you then trying to add points via `addPoint()` or `addSeries()` or `setData()` ?

Comment: Thanks for this your advice. But now I'm still struggling to implement the concept of GearMan and Workers. If you've any experience plz suggest the link. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Now, how can I push that values into the HighChart to draw the chart.

You need to dynamically update the chart with the new data. See the official example how you can do it:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Comment: Thanks for this your advice. But now I'm still struggling to implement the concept of GearMan and Workers. If you've any experience plz suggest the link. :)

Comment: @RiteshAryal not sure what problems do you encounter, but I was using mostly some library like http://socket.io to do the job and use their nice API. See an intro article: http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-socketio-and   and a book: http://www.packtpub.com/socketio-realtime-web-application-development/book